# Find a length knowing certain areas linked to a triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area

$ABC$ is a triangle. $P$ and $Q$ are points on $AB$ and $AC$ of the triangle. $AP=6,$  $AQ=20.$ Area of triangle $APQ$ is equal to area of quadrilateral $PQBC.$

If $PB=QC$ what is length of $PB$ given $BC =25$.
Given BC =25
Find $x$ if  $PB=QC=x$
Im getting too many equations with too many unknowns. Any insight into problem will help

Comment: Have you seen a figure and written down everything you are told on that figure? That usually helps a bit, at least with getting some overview over all the knowns and unknowns.

Answer (score 1):

$$S_{\Delta APQ}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot6\cdot20\sin\measuredangle A$$ and
$$S_{\Delta ABC}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot(6+x)(20+x)\sin\measuredangle A.$$
Thus, since $$S_{\Delta ABC}=2S_{\Delta APQ},$$ we obtain
$$(6+x)(20+x)=2\cdot6\cdot20,$$
which gives $x=4.$

Comment: thanks  i was using angle b did'nt think about a

Comment: @3.14159 You are welcome!